# Python - Sorting a list item by alphabet in a list of lists, and have other lists follow the swapping order

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of lists in Python by the first row (specifically not using Numpy, I know there are many solutions using Numpy but this is a question that specifically asks for a way without using Numpy)

Here is my list of lists:

```
listOfLists = [ ['m', 'e', 'l', 't', 's'],
                ['g', 'p', 's', 'k', 't'],
                ['y', 'q', 'd', 'h', 's'] ]
```

I am looking to sort this list 1) alphabetically BUT 2) only by the first list item, the vertical slices should just follow the order of the first list item. For example:

```
newListofLists = [ ['e', 'l', 'm', 's', 't'],
                   ['p', 's', 'g', 't', 'k'],
                   ['q', 'd', 'y', 's', 'h'] ]
```

The first item in listOfLists is 'melts', which is then sorted alphabetically to become 'elmst'. The rest of the items in the list of list aren't sorted alphabetically, rather they are 'following' the switch and sort pattern of the first item in the list.

I may be being ridiculous but I've spent hours on this problem (which forms part of a larger program). I have tried slicing the first item from the list of lists and sorting it alphabetically on its own, then comparing this to a slice of the first list in the list of lists that HASN'T been sorted, and comparing positions. But I just can't seem to get anything working.

Comment: Why is `numpy` not permitted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can transpose the list using `zip`, sort the transpose, and then transpose that list back into one of the correct dimensions.

```
listOfLists = [ ['m', 'e', 'l', 't', 's'],
                ['g', 'p', 's', 'k', 't'],
                ['y', 'q', 'd', 'h', 's'] ]

print(list(zip(*sorted(zip(*listOfLists)))))
# [('e', 'l', 'm', 's', 't'), ('p', 's', 'g', 't', 'k'), ('q', 'd', 'y', 's', 'h')]
```

Edit:

As @StevenRumbalski points out in the comments, the above will completely sort the vertical slices (by first letter, then second letter, etc), instead of sorting them stably by first letter (sorting by first letter, then by relative order in the input).  I'll reproduce his solution here for visibility:

```
from operator import itemgetter
list(map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(*listOfLists), key=itemgetter(0)))))
```

Comment: There's an extra requirement that still needs satisfied: "BUT 2) only by the first list item, the vertical slices should just follow the order of the first list item."  Solved by adding a key argument to `sorted()`: `from operator import itemgetter; list(map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(*listOfLists), key=itemgetter(0)))))` (I also assumed he still wanted list of list so I converted your outer `list(...)` to `list(map(list, ...))`.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That's how tuples are sorted anyways.  You'll notice that your solution and mine have identical outputs. The only difference is that your solution is a stable sort, while mine isn't.  Since the OP didn't specify, I'm inclined to think it's not a requirement.

Comment: I quoted the OP giving the requirement.  Also see where the title says "have other lists follow the swapping order".  There is a difference between following and influencing.  Given an original list of `[['b', 'a', 'b'], ['z', 'x', 'a']]` I think based on the OPs description a result of `[['a', 'b', 'b'], ['x', 'a', 'z']]` is incorrect and it should be `[['a', 'b', 'b'], ['x', 'z', 'a']]`.  The zipped elements should just be along for the ride, not back seat drivers.

Comment: One final example and I'll drop the point and agree to disagree.  Starting list `[['a','a'],['n','m'],['x','y']]` and starting list `[['a','a'],['x','y'],['n','m']]` would end sorted differently based on row order.  So my point is row order shouldn't matter.  The first row is the key value determining sort order.  Any bleed through violates the question.  I'll quote a third part of the question "The rest of the items in the list of list aren't sorted alphabetically, rather they are 'following' the switch and sort pattern of the first item in the list."

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` is the way to go for both performance and readability:

```
import numpy as np

listOfLists = [ ['m', 'e', 'l', 't', 's'],
                ['g', 'p', 's', 'k', 't'],
                ['y', 'q', 'd', 'h', 's'] ]

lol = np.array(listOfLists)

lol[:, np.argsort(listOfLists[0])]

# array([['e', 'l', 'm', 's', 't'],
#        ['p', 's', 'g', 't', 'k'],
#        ['q', 'd', 'y', 's', 'h']], 
#       dtype='<U1')
```

A non-`numpy` solution:

```
idx = sorted(range(len(lol[0])), key=lol[0].__getitem__)

[list(map(lol[j].__getitem__, idx)) for j in range(len(lol))]
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to use Numpy

Comment: Thanks for taking time to come up with a solution but unfortunately for this specific question I am not looking to use Numpy

Comment: And why not...?